# str_replace within a while loop - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I'm having a problem with `str_replace` within a while loop.

**I've created a couple of variables before a while loop:**

```
$c = 0; // This represents the first object within an array EG: array[0]
$i = 1; // This represents the first [image#] tag within $articleContent
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, when the user inputs '`[image1], [image2], [image3]`' etc into the `$articleContent`, to replace the `[image#]` tags with an `<img src=""/>` containing the file path located within the unserialized array.

The `$images[$c]` variable is pointing to the file path with the id of [0] within the array.

**The issue:**

My expectations were that the loop would naturally count through each `$c` and `$i`, labeling each `[image#]` and array object accordingly, then replacing the `[image#]` tag with the `<img src='images/$imageSplit[$i]'/>`, however this has not been the case.

**The current functionality:**

Say I have three articles being echo'd by the loop. each with three `[image#]` tags in `[image1], [image2] and [image3]`. The first article will **ONLY** show the first image, the second article will only show the second image, and the third article will only show the third.

If anyone could point me in the right direction for the script to replace the image tags accordingly then that'd be much appreciated.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$i = 1; // [image#]
$c = 0; // Array object #
echo "<br/><br/>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
$title = $row['title']; // Grabs the title
$articles = $row['articleContent']; // Grabs the article
$images = unserialize(base64_decode($row['image']));
$imageSplit[$i] = $images[$c]; // [image1] = array[0]

$articles = str_replace("[image$i]","<img src='images/$imageSplit[$i]' width='300px' height='auto'/>","$articles");

// str_replace is only applied once per loop

echo "Title: $title<br/>
Content: $articles<br/>
c = $c<br/>
i = $i<hr/>";

// All variables, including $c and $i are both echoing out correctly, however $i is only being applied correctly once every loop

$c++;
$i++;
}
```

Comment: at quick glance it looks as though you only execute the str_replace once per row .. don't you need to iterate through the array of images in the split? apols if wrong am not much with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say I have three articles being echo'd by the loop. each with three
>   [image#] tags in [image1], [image2] and [image3]

That means you will have to nest 2 loops: a)foreach article, b)foreach one of its images.

Here is a possible way of doing it (I commented out some of the lines that won't be needed):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles";


$res = mysql_query($sql);

//$i = 1; // [image#]
//$c = 0; // Array object #

echo "<br/><br/>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $title = $row['title']; // Grabs the title
    $articles = $row['articleContent']; // Grabs the article
    $images = unserialize(base64_decode($row['image']));
    //  $imageSplit[$i] = $images[$c]; // [image1] = array[0]

    foreach ($images as $index => $img_url) {
        $i = $index + 1;
        $articles = str_replace("[image$i]","<img src='images/$img_url' width='300px' height='auto'/>","$articles");
    }


    echo "Title: $title<br/>
    Content: $articles<br/>
    <br/>
    <hr/>";

    // All variables, including $c and $i are both echoing out correctly, however $i is only being applied correctly once every loop

    //$c++;
    //$i++; 
}
```